# Laravel: view from javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am new at Laravel: simple question, how do you call a view from Javascript? I have a button on a page and I want to go to another page when clicked.

Comment: you create a route pointing to view, or create a route that points to a controller that returns the view

Comment: I have the route just not sure of the javascript

Comment: okay so it sounds like a basic ajax call

Comment: or wait.. if you just want a full redirect on button click, you don't need ajax.. you can put in the button onclick attrib something simple as `onclick='location.href="/path/to/page"'` where page is what your route is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very good question, many developers struggle achieving seemingly simple tasks.

When confronted with the behemoth task of linking a view from another view using javascript, there are many solutions.

A simple one would be to use a simple html anchor, like  But that doesn't use javascript, which is mandatory in today's html5 standards.

Instead lets try to have a javascript solution

```
<!-- create a simple button with a javascript logic so we can call another view -->
<button onclick="call_view('<?= url('/app/view') ?>')">Call view foo</button>
<script>
   /*  call a view, this is where the magic occurs.
       Note: javascript can't build laravel URLs, so we have to embed them in 
       the button above */
   var call_view = function(name)
   {           
       window.location = name;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: "A simple one would be to use a simple html anchor, like But that doesn't use javascript, which is mandatory in today's html5 standards.". What? o_O

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location.assign('{{URL::to('/')}}/your_own_route');
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and  future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: yeah sure my bad Im new in this!